# Waiting for AJAX click method to complete to execute another function. How to implement? : Javascript, AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, promise, async-await

```
var err=0;
  $("#addsell").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
            title: $('#title').val(),
            author: $("#author").val(),
            genre: $('#genre').val(),
            price: $('#price').val(),
            addDate: Date(),
            isbn: $('#isbn').val()
    };

    if(data.title.length==0) {
      $('#errtitle').show();
      err++;
    }
    else $('#errtitle').hide();

    if(data.author.length==0) {
      $('#errauthor').show();
      err++;
    }
    else $('#errauthor').hide();

    if(data.price.toString().length==0) {
      $('#errprice').show();
      err++;
    }
    else $('#errprice').hide();

    if((data.isbn.toString().length==10)||(data.isbn.toString().length==13)||(data.isbn.toString().length==0)) {
      $('#errisbn').show();
      err++;
    }
    else $('#errisbn').hide();

    console.log(data);
  }).then(function() {
    if(err!=0){
      err=0;
      $.post("/api/newbook", data, function(resp, status){
        if(resp==1){
          $('#addform').hide();
          $('#added').show();
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

This is my current code. I know this wont work. What I am trying to do is after executing the onlick ajax call, I want the rest of the code to be run. I dont want it to run before or after. I am not that familiar with promises, async and await. so i need help to implement this.

Comment: What are you trying, are you want to execute ajax method first then execute normal function or execute normal function first then execute ajax function??

Comment: i want to execute the ajax method first. then the function @RanjithUK

Comment: I have added my answer can you try that.

Answer (score 2):

Can you this

```
// handle your ajax function
var ajaxMethod = function() {
   $.post("/api/newbook", function(data) {
       // call your function
       callbackMethod();
   });
}

// handle your callback function
var callbackMethod = function() {

}

$("#addsell").click(function(e) {
    // ...other codes

    // call your ajax function on button click
    ajaxMehtod();
}
```